# Extracting specific text between forward slashes "/" and storing them into a new column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
# A tibble: 60 × 1
   characteristicsMore                                                                                                              
   <chr>                                                                                                                            
 1 "/es/comprar/viviendas/torrox/urbanizacion-santa-rosa/calefaccion/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/torrox/urbanizacion-santa-rosa/terraza…
 2 ""                                                                                                                               
 3 "/es/comprar/viviendas/burgos-capital/san-pedro-y-san-felices/calefaccion/l"                                                     
 4 ""                                                                                                                               
 5 "/es/comprar/viviendas/mancha-real/todas-las-zonas/calefaccion/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/mancha-real/todas-las-zonas/terraza/l|/es…
 6 "/es/comprar/viviendas/torrelavega/centro/calefaccion/l"                                                                         
 7 ""                                                                                                                               
 8 ""                                                                                                                               
 9 "/es/comprar/viviendas/san-vicente-del-raspeig-sant-vicent-del-raspeig/haygon-universidad/calefaccion/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/sa…
```

What I am trying to do is to extract specific information from the text. Using the first, second and third rows as an example I want to extract the following:

```
1) torrox, urbanizacion-santa-rosa
2) ""
3) burgos-capital, san-pedro-y-san-felices
```

Now in the case of the first row it contains two "observations" so I want to extract also the "third" part of the text, which is `calefaccion` and `terraza`  and just paste them into a new column separated by `"|"`.

Expected output using the first 3 rows:

```
col1              col2                       col3
torrox            urbanizacion-santa-rosa    calefaccion | terraza
""                ""                         ""
burgos-capital    san-pedro-y-san-felices    calefaccion
```

Data

```
df = structure(list(characteristicsMore = c("/es/comprar/viviendas/torrox/urbanizacion-santa-rosa/calefaccion/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/torrox/urbanizacion-santa-rosa/terraza/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/torrox/urbanizacion-santa-rosa/piscina/l", 
"", "/es/comprar/viviendas/burgos-capital/san-pedro-y-san-felices/calefaccion/l", 
"", "/es/comprar/viviendas/mancha-real/todas-las-zonas/calefaccion/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/mancha-real/todas-las-zonas/terraza/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/mancha-real/todas-las-zonas/piscina/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/torrelavega/centro/calefaccion/l", "", 
"", "/es/comprar/viviendas/san-vicente-del-raspeig-sant-vicent-del-raspeig/haygon-universidad/calefaccion/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/san-vicente-del-raspeig-sant-vicent-del-raspeig/haygon-universidad/terraza/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/san-vicente-del-raspeig-sant-vicent-del-raspeig/haygon-universidad/piscina/l", 
"", "", "", "/es/comprar/viviendas/moriles/todas-las-zonas/terraza/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/zamora-capital/ciudad-jardin-vista-alegre/calefaccion/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/zamora-capital/ciudad-jardin-vista-alegre/terraza/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/zamora-capital/ciudad-jardin-vista-alegre/piscina/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/navalcarnero/centro/calefaccion/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/navalcarnero/centro/terraza/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/alcaudete/todas-las-zonas/terraza/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/caravaca-de-la-cruz/todas-las-zonas/terraza/l", 
"", "/es/comprar/viviendas/paredes-de-nava/todas-las-zonas/calefaccion/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/ventas-de-huelma/todas-las-zonas/terraza/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/ventas-de-huelma/todas-las-zonas/piscina/l", 
"", "/es/comprar/viviendas/villa-del-prado/todas-las-zonas/calefaccion/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/villa-del-prado/todas-las-zonas/terraza/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/villa-del-prado/todas-las-zonas/piscina/l", 
"", "/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/el-camp-d-en-grassot-i-gracia-nova/calefaccion/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/el-camp-d-en-grassot-i-gracia-nova/terraza/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/el-camp-d-en-grassot-i-gracia-nova/calefaccion/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/el-camp-d-en-grassot-i-gracia-nova/terraza/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/campillos/todas-las-zonas/terraza/l", 
"", "", "/es/comprar/viviendas/salobrena/centro/calefaccion/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/salobrena/centro/terraza/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/santander/numancia-san-fernando/calefaccion/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/sant-joan-despi/les-planes/calefaccion/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/elgoibar/todas-las-zonas/calefaccion/l", 
"", "/es/comprar/viviendas/las-torres-de-cotillas/todas-las-zonas/calefaccion/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/balaguer/todas-las-zonas/calefaccion/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/balaguer/todas-las-zonas/terraza/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/l-alcudia/todas-las-zonas/terraza/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/ubeda/todas-las-zonas/calefaccion/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/ubeda/todas-las-zonas/terraza/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/ubeda/todas-las-zonas/piscina/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/albuixech/todas-las-zonas/calefaccion/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/albuixech/todas-las-zonas/terraza/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/dolores/todas-las-zonas/terraza/l", "/es/comprar/viviendas/algete/algete-pueblo/calefaccion/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/algete/algete-pueblo/terraza/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/algete/algete-pueblo/piscina/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/madrid-capital/nino-jesus/calefaccion/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/madrid-capital/nino-jesus/terraza/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/jaen-capital/renfe-bulevar-1-y-2-fase/calefaccion/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/jaen-capital/renfe-bulevar-1-y-2-fase/terraza/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/el-molar-madrid/todas-las-zonas/calefaccion/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/huercal-de-almeria/todas-las-zonas/terraza/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/huercal-de-almeria/todas-las-zonas/piscina/l", 
"", "/es/comprar/viviendas/oria/todas-las-zonas/terraza/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/oria/todas-las-zonas/piscina/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/granada-capital/centro-sagrario/calefaccion/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/granada-capital/centro-sagrario/terraza/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/granada-capital/centro-sagrario/piscina/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/finestrat/cala-de-finestrat/terraza/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/andujar/todas-las-zonas/piscina/l", "/es/comprar/viviendas/collado-villalba/villalba-estacion/calefaccion/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/collado-villalba/villalba-estacion/terraza/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/torrelavega/nueva-ciudad/calefaccion/l", 
"", "/es/comprar/viviendas/pamplona-iruna/chantrea/calefaccion/l", 
"", "", "", "/es/comprar/viviendas/aguilas/el-rubial/terraza/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/aguilas/el-rubial/piscina/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/sondika/todas-las-zonas/calefaccion/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/la-barceloneta/calefaccion/l", 
"/es/comprar/viviendas/albacete-capital/pedanias-extrarradio/calefaccion/l|/es/comprar/viviendas/albacete-capital/pedanias-extrarradio/terraza/l"
)), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach using `purrr::map` to do the second separation by `|` with `strsplit`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  summarize(col = list(unlist(strsplit(characteristicsMore, "/"))[5:6]), 
            col = list(replace_na(col, "")), 
            col3 = strsplit(characteristicsMore, "\\|"), 
            col3 = paste(purrr::map(col3, 
                     ~ unlist(strsplit(.x, "/"))[7]), collapse=" | ")) %>% 
  unnest_wider(col, names_sep="")
```

output

```
# A tibble: 60 × 3
  col1             col2                      col3                             
  <chr>            <chr>                     <chr>                            
1 "torrox"         "urbanizacion-santa-rosa" "calefaccion | terraza | piscina"
2 ""               ""                        ""                               
3 "burgos-capital" "san-pedro-y-san-felices" "calefaccion"                    
# ℹ 57 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```